# Wondering about a nice combo of ls & cat?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, ls, cat

As `ll`, I use `ls -alh /some/file` frequently, and just as often then, follow immediately with `cat /some/file`. I have to believe this has been addressed with various aliases. And on the next level, with shell functions. I have written a couple hundred aliases, but no shell function. Maybe that's what the doctor orders. Is this an old hat? Is there a shelf remedy? Thank you.

Comment: why not just `cat /some/file`?  If it's not there, `cat` will tell you.  If it is, you get its contents as desired.

Comment: You could consider using the shell's history expansion features ex `cat !!$` to execute `cat` with the last argument of the previous command

Comment: often i `ls` a directory, just for my own edification, and then `cat` a particular file... thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
lcat() {
    ls -alh "$@"
    cat "$@"
}
```

or with `less` instead of `cat`. Or `( ls -alh "$@"; cat "$@") | less` to see the permissions and all in the same browseable listing.

The I would need is something like this:

```
lcd() {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; do
        ls -lvF "$1"
    else
        less "$1"
    fi
}
```

i.e. either take a listing of a directory or view file. There's probably some `less` frontend that already runs `ls` on directories, but anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I was hacking around to understand files that had multiple encodings applied last week, and I came up with this:

```
#.. Show characteristics of a file.

Show () {   #:: (filename)

    printf '\n.. About %s .. at %(%T)T\n' "${1}"
    file "${1}"
    wc "${1}"

    [[ $( file "${1}" ) =~ ASCII ]] && {
        cat -vet "${1}" | nl -ba | head -n 4
        cat -vet "${1}" | nl -ba | tail -n 4
    }
    [[ $( file "${1}" ) =~ ASCII ]] || {
        od -A d -t x4d4o1ac "${1}" > "${1}.od"
        ls -l "${1}.od"
    }
}
```

It might be improved by accepting multiple filenames, and maybe options `-h N` and `-t N` to set the extent of the plain listing.